# jQuery: modular plugin in separate files makes: "TypeError: this.each is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to group my functions into one node and use them on element like this:

```
$('a.add-order').myCMS.order.add();
```

I know that my JavaScript knowledge (jQuery also) is very poor but is possible to have functionalities/methods in different files in structure like this:

```
/js/myCMS/order/add.js
/js/myCMS/order/change.js
/js/myCMS/customer/add.js
/js/myCMS/customer/change.js
```

And after that make on customer page only:

```
<script scr="/js/myCMS/customer/add.js"></script>
<script scr="/js/myCMS/customer/change.js"></script>
```

and on page with orders only those files:

```
<script scr="/js/myCMS/order/add.js"></script>
<script scr="/js/myCMS/order/change.js"></script>
```

My question is because I don't want to have one huge plug-in but have some smaller, easy manageable files which contains my modules.

I've prepared some `order/add/js` file but I got `TypeError: this.each is not a finction` error:

```
(function ($) {
    if ($.fn.myCMS === undefined) {
        $.extend($.fn, {myCMS : function(){return this;} });
    }
    if ($.fn.myCMS.order === undefined) {
        $.extend($.fn.myCMS, {order : function(){return this;} });
    }
    $.extend($.fn.myCMS.order,
        {
            add: function (customer_pesel) {
                return this.each(function(){
                    console.log('setiing PESEL ' + customer_pesel);
                    $(this).click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        alert(customer_pesel);
                    });
                })
            }
        }
    );
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but if the plugins are that small, you'll be better off by just sticking them all in one file, as that saves HTTP requests, and the file will be cached for subsequent pages.

Comment: @adeneo can You help me with this error ?

Comment: I'm guessing somewhere in the strange setup for the plugins, `this` is not a jQuery object, so you have to change it to `$(this).each(...`